# Doubt in a proof related to Dirichlet series in Analytic number theory

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am studying Analytic number theory from Tom M Apostol introduction to analytic number theory.

I have doubt in theorem 11.13 whose image I  am posting- 
[image]

I have these 2 doubts.

> Doubt 1 How can Apostol assume that F(s) is analytic at a= c +1

I know F is analytic in some disk about s=c, but how to be sure that such a disk has radius of convergence > 1 .

> Doubt 2  how to deduce using this theorem the statement given in 5 th line of statement of theorem which is --> if Dirichlet series has a finite abcissa of absolute convergence $\sigma_c$ , then F(s) has a singularity on real axis at point s= $\sigma_c$ .

Can someone please explain.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown what's wrong with my mathjax typing?

Comment: Some quotes "F(s) is analytic at a= c +1 ",  "s=c", "> 1", "s=". All of these are mathematical expressions.

Comment: @user686624 for doubt 2: By the definition of $\sigma_c$, for every $\epsilon > 0$ it's not the case that $F(s)$ is analytic in $Re s > \sigma_c-\epsilon$. So by the rest of the theorem statement (i.e. all but the 5th line), we know it can't be the case that $F(s)$ is analytic in some disk about $s=\sigma_c$; this is what it means for $F$ to have a singularity at $\sigma_c$.

Comment: @mathworker21 yes I got it now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @mathworker21 Confusing the Dirichlet series and its analytic continuation is not good

Comment: Make some efforts, stop asking about every single word of your book...

Comment: @reuns (1) I don't see how I'm confusing the two. (2) why are you so rude (to user686624) lol

Comment: @mathworker21 See his questions, he is literally asking us to rewrite his book page per page. The abscissa of convergence is where the Dirichlet series stops converging, not where the function stops being analytic, for example $\eta(s)$ is entire (even if for a Dirichlet series with non-negative coefficients as we showed both are the same)

Comment: @reuns In every question I have asked I have always written what I have attempted or thought about that particular problem. You have answered a lot of questions asked by me and I am really thankful to you for that . I was really  confused in this theorem that's why I asked it. In many questions asked by me I have doubt only in 1or 2 lines of proof. It's not right say that I am not making any effort or I have asked each result.

Comment: @reuns thanks. I should have said "for every $\epsilon > 0$, it's not the case that the dirichlet series defining $F(s)$ converges for $Re s > \sigma_c-\epsilon$."

Comment: @user686624 maybe the nice way to phrase what reuns is saying is that, if you're having so many questions about the content, maybe you should slow down and think through the material more, which is something I might agree with (I say "might" since I haven't looked through all your questions).

Comment: @mathworker21 Ok. I will keep your advice in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is analytic on $\Re(s) > c$ and on a disk around $c$ thus it is analytic on a disk of radius $1+\epsilon$ around $1+c$ thus (Cauchy integral formula) on this disk it is represented by its Taylor series at $1+c$.

Since $F(s)=\sum_{n\ge 1}f(n)n^{-s},f(n)\ge 0$  all the terms of $$F(c-\epsilon)=\sum_{k\ge 0} (-1-\epsilon)^k \frac{F^{(k)}(1+c)}{k!}$$ are non-negative  thus we can change the order of summation to obtain that $$F(c-\epsilon)=\sum_{n\ge 1}f(n)n^{-c+\epsilon}\quad converges$$

> Whence Dirichlet series (more generally Mellin/Laplace transforms) with non-negative coefficients have a singularity at $\sigma$ their abscissa of convergence

Comment: except the highlighted last paragraph , your proof is clear to me. How did you deduced that there must be singularity at the abcissa of absolute convergence.  Does it is from Using the fact that radius of convergence in Taylor's Theorem is $ | z-z_0 | < \delta $ .Can you please tell if I am right or wrong.